# How to draw a sequence diagram for my University manager MAUI app?

Tags: uml, maui, sequence-diagram

for a school project i need to make an app that allows to create teachers, students, teacher's activities and student's evaluations. I have created a class Person that the classes Teacher and Student extends. But i have trouble learning how to correctly depict such a relationship in a Sequence Diagram. Only things i find online are for HTTP request but never inheritance.

I first need to create a teacher, then an activity linked to the teacher, then a student and then a student evaluation.
Should i make one big Sequence diagram containing everything or can i make several ones ? Please tell me what you think of my first 2 Sequence Diagrams Ever :
[image: Create Professor]

[image: Display ProfessorList]

Since the logic to display Teachers/Activities/Students/Eval Lists are the same i think it would be wise to re-use the 2d diagram, any ideas how to ?

Comment: Inhertance can't be shown i a SD.

Comment: Please note that all reply messages must go back to the sender of the call-message and the label must be the same. If a return value is to be specified, it is shown behind a colon.

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Keep the diagrams as simple as possible but not more.  Prefer several smaller and understandable diagrams rather than a huge and overly complex one that only you will be able to grasp.

### More details

I understand that :

1. Your sequence diagram for the creation of an object tries to show the interaction between all involved objects. Each is already quite complex not to mention that the view could be different for the different kind of objects.
2. You foresee a typical order between the creation of the related objects, but this order seems only indicative.  There are of course some constraints, but in reality, nothing prevents several students to be created for one professor creation, or to interleave the creation of professors and students.

All these elements just reinforce the recommended practice of keeping diagrams as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that some of the order is merely indicative, but you have to create a Teacher before an Activity (composition). It is my first time making such a diagram so i do not know what my teacher (my real teacher for this project) awaits from us. We didnt really see how to make one either. 

How do i integrate smaller sequence diagrams into bigger ones ?
Did i made mistakes in my diagram ?

Comment: @Dumbkopf You can document the constraint of an existing Teacher for the creation of the activity.  You can also have a :Teacher lifeline to refer to the existing teacher, especially if interactions with the teacher are needed in the sequence.  Using an existing teacher (1 lifeline) is much simpler that having all the creation of the teacher in the same diagram.